# Three.js, WebGL, render panorama of six images

Tags: javascript, three.js, panoramas

I built one panorama using three.js and the CSS3D renderer, now I want to do the same using WebGL renderer.

In CSS3D, the following code gets me a perfectly flush and unbreaking panorama:

```
var sides = [
{
url: '/assets/posx.jpg',
position: [ -644, 0, 0 ],
rotation: [ 0, Math.PI / 2, 0 ]
},
{
url: '/assets/negx.jpg',
position: [ 644, 0, 0 ],
rotation: [ 0, -Math.PI / 2, 0 ]
},
{
url: '/assets/posy.jpg',
position: [ 0, 644, 0 ],
rotation: [ Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI ]
},
{
url: '/assets/negy.jpg',
position: [ 0, -644, 0 ],
rotation: [ -Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI ]
},
{
url: '/assets/posz.jpg',
position: [ 0, 0, 644 ],
rotation: [ 0, Math.PI, 0 ]
},
{
url: '/assets/negz.jpg',
position: [ 0, 0, -644 ],
rotation: [ 0, 0, 0 ]
}
];
for (var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {
var side = sides[ i ];
var element = document.createElement('img');
element.width = 1300;
element.height = 1300;
element.src = side.url;
var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
object.position.fromArray(side.position);
object.rotation.fromArray(side.rotation);
scene.add(object);
}
```

[side question: there has to be a better way to format pasted code other than going line by line and hitting space 4 times, right?]

Here is my equivalent code for WebGL, which renders the images, but it is not at all clean, and there is a clear break where the image overlap doesn't make visual sense:

```
var sides = [
        {
            url: '/assets/posx.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/negx.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/posy.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/negy.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/posz.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/negz.jpg'
        }
    ];

    //i chose 8 for this because other numbers i tried rendered interesting
    //distortions into the images
    var k = 8
    for (var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {

        var side = sides[ i ];
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, k, k);
        k += 8;
        geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(side.url)
        });
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);

    }
```

So is there a standard method of projecting six images into a panorama using Three.js and the WebGl rendering engine?

Comment: I'm trying to follow from this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap, but can't seem to get it to load just the scene, without floating heads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for is named "skybox".

There is a most simple example:
https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Skybox.html

in this part you inserting images:

```
var imagePrefix = "images/dawnmountain-";
var directions  = ["xpos", "xneg", "ypos", "yneg", "zpos", "zneg"];
var imageSuffix = ".png";
var skyGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5000, 5000, 5000 );   

var materialArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( imagePrefix + directions[i] + imageSuffix ),
        side: THREE.BackSide
    }));
var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialArray );
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeometry, skyMaterial );
scene.add( skyBox );
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I had to look at the source of the example provided to get it exactly right, but it was skybox that i was looking for.